# test performance on different methods of obtaining input in Python

Tags: python, input, performance-testing

Consider a line of input for Python 3 that looks like this:

```
1 4 99 8 7
```

Code needs to treat these inputs as numbers, so the following different ways of getting this or like input from the user is devised:

method one:

```
inputLst = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

method two:

```
inputLst = map(int, input().split())
```

How do you get an accurate performance check on code using the two different methods when the user has to interact with the code like this during testing?  Is there an effective way?

Comment: If this is Python3, you need `list(map(...))`, as `map()` won't actually compute anything unless asked for.

Answer (score 3):

The input time is constant. It won't change the difference in speed if you replace it with a constant string.

If you use the `timeit` module, either replace `input()` with a constant in the statement, or declare the function in the setup
    import timeit
    import random

```
tests = []
random_input = ' '.join(str(random.randint(1000, 9999)) for _ in range(1000))
setup = 'def input():\n    return ' + repr(random_input)

tests.append(timeit.timeit('[int(i) for i in input().split()]', setup, number=10000))
tests.append(timeit.timeit('list(map(int, input().split()))', setup, number=10000))
for i, time in enumerate(tests, 1):
    print('Test #{} took {:.3f} seconds to run 10000 trials.'.format(i, time))
```

Which the output is (Python2):

```
Test #1 took 2.477 seconds to run 10000 trials.
Test #2 took 2.079 seconds to run 10000 trials.
```

(Python3):

```
Test #1 took 1.448 seconds to run 10000 trials.
Test #2 took 1.152 seconds to run 10000 trials.
```

so `map()` is indeed faster in both versions.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this yourself using python's timing functions (import time) and setting runamount to a high number to get consistent results.

```
total = 0

for i in range(runamount):
    start = time.time()

    #your code here    

    total += time.time() - start
return (total / runamount)
```

Run it for both and see which one goes more quickly to figure out which you should use.